# Exp:resso Store: Show customers email in template

Tags: expresso-store, email, tags

My client has requested that a customers email address be placed in an email template. This can obviously be retrieved using the member details if the customer has chosen to be a member, but how do I get the email address if the customer hasn't opted to register as a member please?

Cheers

Tom

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. The tag `{order_email}` works in the email templates.